# ошибка на python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

помогите с предпоследней строкой(я хз как сделать без этой ошибки)

```
#импорт библиотек
import random

#ввод переменных
print("ваш массив")
mass=[]
n=int(0)
#рандом массива
for i in range(20):
mass.append(random.randint(1,20)-10)
print(mass)

#новый массив
print('')
print("ваш новый массив")

#вывод нового массива
for i in range(20):
    if mass > 0:
        print(mass)
```

вывод

```
ваш массив
[-7, 2, 6, 4, -1, 1, -9, 3, 3, -9, -7, 3, 2, 7, -8, -3, 4, -1, -1, -8]
ваш новый массив
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "main.py", line 20, in <module>
        if n > 0:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 3):

Если вы хотели вывести только положительные элементы списка, то и сравнивайте элементы списка с нулём, а не весь список. И выводите тоже элемент списка, а не весь список каждый раз:

```
#вывод нового массива
for i in range(20):
    if mass[i] > 0:
        print(mass[i], end=', ')
```

Пример вывода:

```
ваш массив
[2, -4, -2, -4, 9, 4, 3, -4, 10, -4, -2, -9, 4, -1, 10, 1, 10, 9, -1, 8]

ваш новый массив
2, 9, 4, 3, 10, 4, 10, 1, 10, 9, 8,
```

Comment: спасиб за ответ, очень выручил!